# How to disable "Collect unused imports" after renaming something in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

After renaming anything in Android Studio, it starts a process to collect unused imports and Android Studio just freezes for about 5-10 seconds. This is very annoying. How can I disable this?

I have already disabled "Optimize imports on the fly" under "Auto Import". Unfortunately, that does not have any effect on this behaviour.

Comment: I am also seeing this problem.  Very annoying especially with Kotlin project